# mql4 iLowest() giving the wrong candle ID?

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mql5, metatrader5

I am trying to get the lowest candle ID inside for loop

Use case:

**Step 1:**  i am using for loop to check candle ID of the candle on which the indicator is visible most recently, and then break the loop

**Step 2:** i am using iLowest() to get the candle ID of the bar having the lowest value out of 5 ,

**Step3 :** using the candle id (from step 2) to get low value  of that candle and then calculate the SL for that candle.

But i am getting wrong ID of candle in **Step 2.**

please have a look at the below screenshot, the comment of bar should be 74 but it shows 135
[image]

**Here is my code :**

```
   for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
           {
          double btt1= iCustom(NULL,0,"Arrows",0,i);
          double btt2= iCustom(NULL,0,"Arrows",1,i);
          if(btt1!=EMPTY_VALUE)
            {
             if(Digits==5|| Digits==3)
                   {
                    baar =iLowest(NULL,0,MODE_LOW,5+i,i);
                    lowestb = Low[baar];
                    stoploss = lowestb- 20*Point*10; 
                    Comment("value of i :  ",i,"    value of baar :  " , baar );
                     ObjectCreate(chart_ID,name,OBJ_LABEL,sub_window,0,0);
                     ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_XDISTANCE,xx1x);
                     ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_YDISTANCE,yy1y);
                     ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_CORNER,corner); 
                     ObjectSetString(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_TEXT, stoploss   ); 
                     ObjectSetString(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_FONT,font); 
                     ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_FONTSIZE,font_size); 
                     ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_COLOR,clrRed);            
                     ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_BACK,back);
 
                   break;
                   }
                  
                   }
                   
                   }
```

**What am i doing wrong ?**

Comment: Without knowing how the custom indicator "Arrows" is coded or what it is returning, it's difficult to help

Answer (score 0):

Change it to :

```
baar =iLowest(NULL,0,MODE_LOW,5,i);
```

Because the 4th parameter of the iLowest function counts the number of bars that you want to analyze starting from the counter i (the last parameter).